# Undefined en consola al listar json con jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

La consola me envia un undefined al consultar elemento ajax en consola.

Estoy listando un Json en consola utilizando la API MARVEL y al seleccionar cada uno de los elementos AJAX y mostrarlos por separado con un console.log , esta me arroja un Undefined.

```
 $.get({
        url: 'https://gateway.marvel.com/v1/public/characters?' + "&ts=" + ts + "&apikey=" + publicKey + "&hash=" + hash,
        dataType: 'json',

        success: function (respuesta) {

            // Guardamos la respuesta de la URL en una variable.
            var personajes = respuesta.data;
            console.log(respuesta);

            // $.each es un bucle para recorrer objetos,  que dentro de ella va una funcion 

            // index entrega la posición de dicho elemento en el bucle
            $.each(personajes, function (index, personaje) {
                console.log(personaje);
                //muestra en consola la lista de personajes por separados


                console.log(personaje.id);
                console.log(personaje.name);
                console.log(personaje.description);



            });


        },
        // Muestra un error en pantalla si es que no se pueden obtener los datos de la URL.
        error: function (error) {
            console.error("Problemas con el server para listar marvel")
            console.error(error)
        },
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        }

    });
```

Comment: La pregunta esta incompleta... deberias de publicar el contenido de `respuesta`

Answer (score 0):

para poder acceder a los datos de, respuesta, debe hacer una conversión JSON, de ésta forma, 
`var resJson = JSON.parse(respuesta)` al hacer ésta conversión ya puede acceder al valor de las propiedades `resJson.data` o directamente `var resJson = JSON.parse(respuesta).data` , siempre que llamamos API´s, llegan las estructuras JSON como string, mas no como objetos.

Answer (score 0):

> console.log(**typeof** respuesta)

1.Si es String, entonces basta con JSON.parse(respuesta)
2.Si es un objeto, y data es un String, entonces JSON.parse(respuesta.data)

> const personajes = JSON.parse(/* caso 1 o 2 */);